# how to link to detail page(single.php?) in a wp_loop

Tags: wp-query

I have made wp_query like below. This is some part of them. And it works.

```
$args = .....;
$query = new WP_Query($args);
while($query->have_posts() ) :
    $query->the_post();
    ?>
        <div class="each">
            <h4><?php the_title(); ?> </h4>
        </div>
<?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

This shows like this.

```
<div>title 1</div>
<div>title 2</div>
<div>title 3</div>
...
```

At this point, when I click one of the titles, it needs to link to the details of the clicked post. But I don''t know how to link to the detail page. I think it should be linked to 'single.php'. is this right? and how to link to that detail page(maybe singles.php)? thank you.

Comment: You don't link to templates. Use `the_permalink()` to dynamically output the correct URL for the post/page. When rending that post/page it will choose the template according to the [template hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace with below code :

```
<?php
$args = .....;
$query = new WP_Query($args);
while($query->have_posts() ) :
$query->the_post();
    ?>
        <div class="each">
            <h4><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute();?>"><?php the_title();?></a></h4>
        </div>
<?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Code:

```
<h4><?php the_title(); ?> </h4>
```

Replace With this:

```
    <?php 
     the_title( sprintf( '<h4 class="entry-title"><a href="%s" rel="bookmark">', esc_url( get_permalink() ) ), '</a></h4>' ); 
    ?>
```